# rearranging a table with bash/awk

Tags: bash, awk, datatable, concatenation

I have a file with almost 2 hundred columns, each with a varying number of rows similar to the following (but approximately 80 rows in length):

```
column1  column2 column3 column4....
abc      def     ghi     jki
lmn      opq     rst     uvw
xyz              abc     def
ghi              jkl
```

what I need to do is effectively concatenate the columns with column1 being the name of the original column and column2 being the values that were in the rows, something like the following:

```
column1  abc
column1  lmn
column1  xyz
column1  ghi
column2  def
column2  opq
column3  ghi
column3  rst
column3  abc
column3  jkl
column4  ...
```

I have very limited skills and have tried to piece together the following, but I'm having no luck:

```
awk -F"\t" '{ for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { l=length($i) ; if ( l > linesize[i] ) linesize[i]=l ; }} END \
{ for (l=1;l <= NF; l++) for (j=2;j<=NR;j++) printf "%d/t%d\n",NR==1($l),!(NR==$j&&NF==$l)="" ;; }'\
 file_in.txt > file_out.txt
```

I've done extensive searching and have been unable to find anything that helps (I know for sure that some of the setting of the NR and NF is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it), so any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's long enough to do in pure `awk` that it's easier to throw it all in a script file of its own instead of doing it as a one-liner:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { FS = "\t" }
NR == 1 {
    for (c = 1; c <= NF; c++)
        headers[c] = $c
    maxcol = NF
    next
}
{
    for (c = 1; c <= NF; c++)
        if ($c != "")
            results[c] = results[c] headers[c] "\t" $c "\n"
}
END {
    for (c = 1; c <= maxcol; c++)
        printf "%s", results[c]
}
```

Usage:

```
$ ./rowify.awk < input.tsv
column1 abc
column1 lmn
column1 xyz
column1 ghi
column2 def
column2 opq
column3 ghi
column3 rst
column3 abc
column3 jkl
column4 jki
column4 uvw
column4 def
```

This just appends each column name + column value as a new line in a string to the appropriate entry in an array, and then prints them all out at the end.

Alternative one liner with `awk` in combination with [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/):

```
$ datamash --no-strict transpose < input.tsv | awk '{ for (c = 2; c <= NF; c++) if ($c != "N/A") print $1 "\t" $c }'
column1 abc
column1 lmn
column1 xyz
column1 ghi
column2 def
column2 opq
column3 ghi
column3 rst
column3 abc
column3 jkl
column4 jki
column4 uvw
column4 def
```

The `transpose` command switches rows and columns, so lines looks like `column1 abc lnm ...` and then the awk just splits that up into individual lines.

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I used the script file version and it worked exactly as needed. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've made this. Gen test file

```
for i in {1..10}; { echo "column1 1_$RANDOM" >> file; }
for i in {1..5} ; { echo "column2 2_$RANDOM" >> file; }
for i in {1..7} ; { echo "column3 3_$RANDOM" >> file; }
for i in {1..4} ; { echo "column4 4_$RANDOM" >> file; }
```

For this test file

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A col
mapfile raw < file
for item in "${raw[@]}"; {
    sub=($item)
    col[$sub]+="${sub[@]:1} "
}

N=0
for name in ${!col[@]}; {
    sub=(${col[$name]})
    sub_lenght=${#sub[@]}
    (( $sub_lenght > $N )) && { N=$sub_lenght; longest=$name; }
}

I=0
echo "${!col[@]}"
for i in ${col[$longest]}; {
    line=
    for name in ${!col[@]}; { 
        sub=(${col[$name]})
        line+="${sub[$I]}\t"
    }
    ((I++))
    printf "$line\n"
}
```

The output

```
$ ./test 
column2 column3 column1 column4
2_17726 3_28940 1_1605  4_16951 
2_4722  3_22401 1_22079 4_15812 
2_8031  3_4652  1_20680 4_11615 
2_9130  3_12552 1_7640  4_22234 
2_28572 3_9818  1_26144     
        3_13568 1_28112     
        1_30364     
        1_2937      
        1_16697
```

Comment: Thanks heaps for the response Ivan, but it does the reverse of what I was after. I have been provided with a good answer.